# Static and dynamic Semantic-UI tabs

Tags: jquery, dynamic, tabs, semantic-ui

Can anyone help me understand how to make SemanticUI Tabs where few of them are static and few dynamically loadable? Using apiSettings/url makes all tabs loadable. Using data-url attribute does something, but ... not sure if that's as expected because i couldn't find any info about that in SUI documentation.

Is the only way to do this is trough some api magic like here [laravel views in Semantic-UI tabbed layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812876/laravel-views-in-semantic-ui-tabbed-layout) ?
and yes - i need completely separate urls not use url template {tab}

```
<div class="ui  tabular menu">
    <div class="item" data-tab="tab_1">Static Tab</div>
    <div class="item" data-tab="tab_2">Dynamically Loading</div>
    <div class="item" data-tab="tab_3">Also dynamic</div>
</div>
<div class="ui tab" data-tab="tab_1">Static content</div>
<div class="ui tab" data-tab="tab_2" data-url="tabs.php?tabs_callback=callback"></div>
<div class="ui tab" data-tab="tab_3" data-url="vote.php?foo=bar&qwe=rty"></div>
```

Is it at all possible to easily have static and dynamic tabs in the same tab widget?

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.